# Tools available : contract deployment / calling - Alphanet / mainnet

Tags: smart-contracts, deploy

Are there any tools available running on web-page, browser plugin, desktop or mobile that allow me to do the following :

- Deploy contracts - alphanet / mainnet
- Call contracts - alphanet / mainnet
- Get detailed contract information - alphanet / mainnet

I know I could spin up a node myself for contract interfacing but these tools would save me time in node maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.liquidity-lang.org/edit/) you can deploy and call contracts written in liquidity, and view the compiled michelson, among other things,